# generate custom text lines from file with specific structure

Tags: java, javascript, php, text

I have 1 text file containing Ips .Like this
iptextfile.txt

```
10.0.0.1
192.168.1.1
123.123.123.123
```

And I want to select the iptextfile and export it to an other file named export.txt and looks like this:

export.txt

```
Ip Number 10.0.0.1 Num 10.0.0.1  
Ip Number 192.168.1.1 Num 192.168.1.1
Ip Number 123.123.123.123 Num 123.123.123.123
```

Could you suggest any software I can do this or some code PHP, Java or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
<?php
    $lines = file('ipaddresses.txt');
    $newtext = '';
    foreach ($lines as $line) 
    {
        $newtext.= "Ip Number {$line} Num {$line}}\n";
    }
    $handle = fopen('export.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($handle, $newtext);
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$in = fopen('iptextfile.txt','r');
$out = fopen('export.txt','w');
while($ip = trim(fgets($in))) {
    if(empty($ip)) continue;
    fputs($out, 'Ip Number '.$ip.' Num '.$ip."\n");
}
fclose($in);
fclose($out);

?>
```